# Wordnet issue in Java with printing verbs

Tags: java, wordnet

The code below is part of a wordnet based program in Java with an event below that acts when a button is clicked on the GUI that I have. Basically using wordnet, you search a word and then when it finds the word, it displays all of the meanings of that word. Since I have been using Netbeans, "System.out.println" prints all of the meanings of the words out perfectly fine on its terminal, but on the GUI on "jTextField2" (where I want it to print the meanings on) it prints the last one and not all of them. Another strange thing is that it prints the last one into the middle of the text field when I want the outputs going from top of the text field down to the bottom if applicable.

```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        JWNL.initialize(new FileInputStream("C:\\jwnl14-rc2\\config\\file_properties.xml"));
        Dictionary wordnet = Dictionary.getInstance();
        String text = jTextField1.getText().trim(); //the word is inputted in jTextField1
        text = text.replace(' ','_');
        jTextField2.setText("Searches for " + text + ":");
        IndexWord verb = wordnet.getIndexWord(POS.NOUN, text);
        Synset[] verbsenses = verb.getSenses();
        for (Synset verbsense : verbsenses) 
        {
             System.out.println(verb + ": " + verbsense.getGloss()); //displays every output in the terminal line
             jTextField2.setText(verb + ": " + verbsense.getGloss()); //only displays the last output from a particular word
        }

    } catch (JWNLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

  }
```

If anyone can help that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you call jTextField2.setText(...), you are ***replacing*** the text that exists in that field with new text.

A JTextField is probably not what you want - it only allows a single line of text.
You should look at JTextArea.